# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'unsigned short'

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, command-line-interface

How to create array of enum values? I can't rid of this error:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array ^' to 'unsigned
>   short'

```
enum class CS_SENSOR_RESULT {

   OPERATION_PASSED = 0,

    OPERATION_FAILED,
} 

array<CS_SENSOR_RESULT>^ GetResults()
{ 
    array<SENSOR_RESULT>^ result = gcnew array<SENSOR_RESULT>(size);

   return result[x]=(CS_SENSOR_RESULT)(int)d5->setDoorState(fa, door, left, right);  // Here I got error
}
```

Comment: You Keep changing the question and making my answer out of date. Please don't make me keep editing to keep up!

Comment: I rolled the question back. Don't write answers in questions. And there's really no point writing answers that bear no relation to the question!

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to setDoorState is a scalar value of type unsigned short, but you are passing an array. That's what the compiler is telling you. We cannot tell you specifically what to pass instead, since we know none of the details, but clearly it's no good passing an array!

You are returning a single element, result[x], rather than the array, result. You need to assign the element, then return the array.

```
result[x] = (CS_SENSOR_RESULT) (int) d5->setDoorState(...);
return result;
```

Comment: d5->setDoorState() returns C++ SESNOR_RESULT

Answer (score 0):

I changed `(CS_SENSOR_RESULT)(int)(...)` to `static_cast<CS_SENSOR_RESULT>(...)` and it worked. Here is the full code:

```
array<CS_SENSOR_RESULT>^ GetResults(int size)
{ 
   array<SENSOR_RESULT>^ result = gcnew array<SENSOR_RESULT>(size);

   for(int x=0;x<size;x++)                 
   {        
        result[x] = gcnew CS_SENSOR_RESULT();
        SENSOR_RESULT doorresult= d5->setDoorState(fa, door, left, right);
        result[x]=static_cast<CS_SENSOR_RESULT>(doorresult);  
   }
}
```